# How to add hyperlink to APA-style citation call-out?

Tags: citing, apa-style

I use APA citation style for my article. I tried some package for APA citation, but it seems that only `{apacite}` with `\shortciteA` and `\shortcite` produces the desired results for references with many authors, i.e. the citation appears as "First author et al. (year)" or "(First author et al.,year)"

I would like to add hyperlink to my citation, maybe change the citation to blue and link it to the references section. I add the package hyper ref in the preamble, like this

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,
   bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
```

but it does not work. Could anyone show me how to do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \let\cite\shortciteA
    \let\citep\shortcite
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{document}
    heloo
    \begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{abdon14,
      title={Fiscal policy and growth in developing Asia},
      author={Abdon, Arnelyn and Estrada, Gemma Bolotaulo and Lee, Minsoo and Park, Donghyun},
      year={2014}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \cite{abdon14}
    \section*{References}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{bib}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, if you wish to use the natbib-style citation commands `\citet` and `\citep` while using the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style, you must load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

Do not, repeat **not**, attempt to (re)create `\citet` and `\citep` via simple `\let` instructions.

If you follow this basic intruction, then the instruction

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

will behave exactly as one would expect it to.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@techreport{abdon14,
  title        = "Fiscal Policy and Growth in Developing {Asia}",
  author       = "Abdon, Arnelyn May and Estrada, Gemma Esther
                  and Lee, Minsoo and Park, Donghyun",
  year         = "2014",
  institution  = "Asian Development Bank",
  series       = "ADB Economics Working Paper Series",
  type         = "Economics Working Paper",
  number       = "412",
  url          = "http://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:ris:adbewp:0412",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % be sure to set 'natbibapa' option
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} % optional, but highly recommended
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citet{abdon14}; \citep{abdon14}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is exactly what I would like to do.